# How can I get the return value of a superclass method without executing it?

Tags: java, equals, hierarchy

This is my superclass equals() method:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    Car c = (Car)other;
    if(this.make.equals(c.make) && this.model.equals(c.model)){

        System.out.println("True, Cars are equal");
        return true;
    }

    else 
        System.out.println("False, Cars are not equal");
    return false;

}
```

Here is my subclass equals() method:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    GreenCar g = (GreenCar) other;
    if(super.equals(g)==true){

        if (this.type.equals(g.type)) {
            System.out.println("True, Cars are equal");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("False, Cars are not equal");

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("False, Cars are not equal");
    return false;
}
```

When it runs the check at `if(super.equals(g)==true){` it executes the method and prints out true or false. How can I just check the return value?

Comment: Please change supper to super. Also, if you want your `equals()` method to not print anything, just remove the print statements.

Comment: Remove the calls to `System.out.println` in your ***`super`** class*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run the method without letting it print anything.

This is why most of your methods *should not* have "side effects" (like printing things to the screen).

Remove the `println` calls from both `equals` methods. Add them to the code that calls `equals` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by adding it to the code that calls equals? like in my main method?

Comment: @LesterRamos: somewhere you wrote `something.equals(somethingElse)` right? And you want it to print whether they're equal?

Comment: Yeah originally i wanted to call the method like this:     c1.equals(c2); but now i would have to include it in a System.out.println() if i take out the "side effects" of the method; so it would just print out "true" or "false" which is very plain.

Comment: @LesterRamos `if(c1.equals(c2)) System.out.println("They are equal"); else System.out.println("They aren't equal");`

Comment: Or (if you know about `?:`) you can abbreviate that to `System.out.println(c1.equals(c2) ? "They are equal" : "They aren't equal");`

Answer (score 0):

Like people have said you need to take out those println's if you want it to not print something when you call it, because every time you call the method it will print.

Just as a note you can shorten some of your methods by taking out those elses since it will have returned before getting to the next body of code if the conditional was true. For example

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    Car c = (Car)other;
    if(this.make.equals(c.make) && this.model.equals(c.model))//if this is true
        return true;//the method ends here
    return false;//if the method hasn't ended yet then the conditional must be false
 }
```

Also I noticed that you used `if(super.equals(g)==true)` but if you just put `if(super.equals(g))` it has the same effect since you are putting in a boolean and it checks if the boolean is true or not. If you want to have the effect of `if((boolean)==false)` you can do `if(!(boolean))` because it checks if the opposite of that boolean is true.

Answer (score 0):

In your `super` class, you could write something like

```
protected boolean equals(Object other, boolean debug) {
    if (other instanceof Car) {
        Car c = (Car) other;
        if (this.make.equals(c.make) && this.model.equals(c.model)) {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("True, Cars are equal");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("False, Cars are not equal");
    }
    return false;
}
```

then you can modify your `equals()` method (still in the `super` class) like

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return equals(other, true); // <-- default to debug.
}
```

next your `subclass` should call the version that takes the `debug` flag like

```
if (super.equals(g, false)) { // you don't need == true
```

Alternatively, you might use a `Logger` and enable and disable `debug` on demand.